# dumping data with correct column type

Tags: mysql

I have a **datetime(6)** column type that I need to change to **datetime** without using alter table statement.
I guess the "compatible" mode should work.

```
# mysqldump dbo apexsql_log_connection_monitor_session --no-data --compatible=ansi,no_key_options,no_table_options,no_field_options

CREATE TABLE "apexsql_log_connection_monitor_session" (
  "SESSION_ID" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "START_TIME" datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  "STOP_TIME" datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  "SERVER_NAME" varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("SESSION_ID")
);
```

Is there any way to dump the data using only datetime column type (without the 6).